# Prevent Hover Function if Body has class in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a hover function that shows and hides div on hover of a link and another function that automatically hides and shows the div after sometime. This works fine.

I would like the disable the hover function on touch devices. I use the following code to add the class `user-is-touching' on touch devices:

```
window.addEventListener('touchstart', function onFirstTouch() {
document.body.classList.add('user-is-touching');
window.USER_IS_TOUCHING = true;
$(".o-c, .c-f, .i-c, .c-u").unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave')
window.removeEventListener('touchstart', onFirstTouch, false);
}, false);
```

```js
var homeLinks = ['i-t', 'o-c', 'c-f', 'i-c', 'c-u'];
var currentLink = 0;
var hovered = false;

$(".home-link").hover(function() {
  hovered = true;
  $('.home-' + homeLinks[currentLink]).hide();
  $('[data-hover=' + homeLinks[currentLink] + ']').toggleClass('default-underline');
  currentLink = homeLinks.indexOf($(this).attr('data-hover'));
  $('[data-hover=' + homeLinks[currentLink] + ']').toggleClass('default-underline');
  $('.home-' + homeLinks[currentLink]).show();
}, function() {
  hovered = false;
});

var autoNavInterval = setInterval(autoNav, 1000);

function autoNav() {
  if (hovered === false) {
    $('.home-' + homeLinks[currentLink]).hide();
    $('[data-hover=' + homeLinks[currentLink] + ']').toggleClass('default-underline');
    currentLink++;
    if (currentLink >= homeLinks.length) {
      currentLink = 0;
    }
    $('[data-hover=' + homeLinks[currentLink] + ']').toggleClass('default-underline');
    $('.home-' + homeLinks[currentLink]).show();
  }
}
```

```css
.left-fill {
  background: #0000006b;
  height: 100vh;
}

.right-fill {
  background: pink;
  height: 100vh;
}

.vc_col-sm-6 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.pivot-nav {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  text-align: left;
}

.pivot-nav li a {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.pivot-nav li a.default-underline::after,
.pivot-nav li a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

.pivot-nav:hover a.default-underline:not(:hover)::after {
  width: 0;
}

.pivot-nav li a::after {
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  transition: width 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 0;
}

.home-o-c,
.home-c-f,
.home-i-c,
.home-c-u {
  display: none;
}

.our-company {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  height: 50vh;
}

.cf2 {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-fill text-left wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-6">

  <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <p class="home-i-t">TEXT One</p>
    <p class="home-o-c">TEXT One</p>
    <p class="home-c-f">TExt for C f.</p>
    <p class="home-i-c">Some more text fo i c.</p>
    <p class="home-c-u">Get in touch </p>

  </div>
</div>



<div class="home-fill right-fill text-right wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-6">

  <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <ul class="pivot-nav">
      <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a data-hover="o-c" class="home-link" href="#" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2">O C</a></li>
      <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a data-hover="c-f" class="home-link" href="#" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2">C F</a></li>
      <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a data-hover="i-c" class="home-link" href="#" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2">I C</a></li>
      <li class="pivot-nav-item" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2"><a data-hover="c-u" class="home-link" href="#">C U</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `pointer-events: none` ?

Comment: `if (document.body.classList.contains('user-is-touching')) return;` ?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey how would this bee added to jquery?

Comment: @Axnyff this does not work

Answer (score 0):

instead of waiting for the first "touch-event" to determine if its a touch-device you could check it like this:

```
var is_touch = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;


if(!is_touch){
  $(".home-link").hover(function() { ... });

}
```